# To what extent is Nietzsche an "Idealist?"

Tags: kant, nietzsche, transcendental-idealism

I am well aware of Nietzsche's prolonged and often prolific critiques of what he referred to as "Idealism," yet I am curious as to the extent which two of his ideas in particular, namely  Perspectivalism and the Will to Power, were influenced by German Idealists, especially Kant in the case of the latter.

Comment: Nietzsche was surely influenced by Kant and German idealists, mostly in  rejecting what they had to offer, but also building on it in his own way. So was Marx, which does not make him an idealist either. Even more so, Nietzsche was influenced by Schopenhauer, both an exponent and a subverter of Kant and Hegel. Will to power comes from there. Perspectivism is an epistemological rather than a metaphysical position, and has little precedent in classical idealism, although Leibniz's monadology can be reinterpreted that way. Nietzsche was the first to develop the position systematically.